# redefined error asm in assembly programming

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am learning assembly coding, here's my code of Greatest common divisor (GCD), after trying to compile the code, it gives this error :
**error: symbol 'etq1' redefined

error: symbol 'etq2' redefined**

```
segment .data        
    r db 0     
segment .bss   
segment .text   
global _main  
extern _printf  
_main:   
    mov al,[200]  
    mov bl,[201]  
etq1:   cmp al,bl   
    jb fin   
etq2:   call PGCD   
    mov [202],bl    
fin:   
ret
```

and heres's the call function
;

```
function
    PGCD:     
        mov [r],al      
    reste:  cmp [r],bl      
        jb etq1       
        sub [r],bl      
    etq1:   cmp [r],0       
        jne etq2           
    etq2:   mov al, bl      
        mov bl,[r]        
        jmp PGCD      
    ret
```

Comment: So it is indeed a double-defined symbol. The error message seems clear, what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the labels in your asm source are global. Local labels (those which have smaller scope of visibility) are usually have special syntax. For example [nasm](https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/nasm-local-label.html)

> gives special treatment to symbols beginning with a period. A label beginning with a single period is treated as a local label, which means that it is associated with the previous non-local label.

ARM asm allows numeric labels, etc. You have to read documentation on your assembly program to find out specific syntax.